# compareTo sets 10 before 2 when sorting on value

Tags: java, list, comparable, compareto

Let me give you an example for what i'm trying to achieve. Look only to the numbers because it's a card game.

I have:

```
harten5 klaveren4 klaveren7 schoppen5 ruiten5 schoppen2 klaverenheer schoppenheer schoppendame schoppen6 klaverenboer schoppen8 ruitenheer klaveren6...
```

I want to sort this on the value to:

```
schoppen2 harten2 ruiten2 klaveren2 ruiten3 harten3 schoppen3 klaveren3 klaveren4 harten4 schoppen4 ruiten4 harten5 schoppen5 ruiten5...
```

But i get the 10 before the 2 like this:

```
schoppen10 ruiten10 harten10 klaveren10 schoppen2 harten2 ruiten2 klaveren2 ruiten3 harten3 schoppen3 klaveren3...
```

This is my basic compareTo Method:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Card p) {
    return this.value.compareTo(p.value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `String`'s (I guess `this.value` is `String`) `compareTo` compares lexicographically, whilst you want numerically. So you have to reimplement it, take substring (or find the last part which is a digit, convert it to `Integer` and then user `compareTo` on that `Integer`.

In general, I think your class Card could be improved a bit. In particular, I would rewrite it:

```
       class Card {
         private String value;
         private Integer rank;


        ...

         public int compareTo(Card c) {
          // Additional logic if you need to consider 
// also value (suite) in comparison
          return this.rank.compareTo(c.rank);
        }
       }
```

But you can also use an `enum` for this purpose.

[String java API compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: you understand my problem but i can't use int(see comment on other answer)

Comment: I know... I tried collecting the return into an array but without success

Comment: You must rewrite the class to have suite and rank separate as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want the reverse order? If so, then just change your implementation to this:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Card p) {
    return p.value.compareTo(this.value);
}
```

It really depends on what the type of "value" is and how the "compareTo" is implemented. Alternatively, you could just do this if "value" is an integer:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Card p) {
    return this.value - p.value;
}
```

Comment: I do not want to reverse it and value is a string and not an int but a string because a card dek goes like this... 8 9 10 clubs diamonds...

Comment: I does everything right except that the 10 is placed before the 2

Comment: It's because 10 is being compared as a String. '1' is before '2'. That's why. And therefore, '1' followed by '0' comes before '2'.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your value is stored as an String. If you do not want to change the data type of value, you can implement the compareTo method in the following way:

```
    public int compareTo(Card p) {
        return Integer.parseInt(this.value).compareTo(Integer.parseInt(p.value));
    }
```